# NodeMCU and expected ';' before wrong ' " '

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, code-review, compilation-errors

I am creating a home weather station but the Arduino IDE shows

```
"expected ';' before 'viewport'".
```

It detects wrong quotation marks. My code:

```
     String message2 = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
  message2 += "<head>";
  message2 +=  "<title>Bootstrap Example</title>";
  message2 += " <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">";
  message2 += "<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">";
  message2 +=  "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>";
  message2 +=  "<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>";
  message2 += "</head>";
  message2 += "<body>";
  message2 += "<div class="container">";
  message2 +=  "<h2>Teplotná Stanica</h2>";
  message2 +=  "<p>Teplota:";
  message2 +=  dht.readTemperature();
  message2 +=  "</p>";

  server.send(200, "text/html", message2);}
```

Can someone tell me what´s wrong?
I am using Arduino IDE

Comment: Have you looked at your quotes yet? *All* of them?

Comment: I wonder who upvoted this question.

Comment: Your question has been answered. Please, accept the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C you can not use quotation marks inside quotation marks (thus nested).

Replace

```
message2 += " <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">";
```

to

```
message2 += " <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">";
```

By using the escape character \  it means that \" is a character (")  instead of the beginning or start of a string.