# unable to find string literal operator 'operator"" stylesheet'

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I am new to programing in C and I get this error:

```
unable to find string literal operator 'operator"" stylesheet'.
```

I am making a website for NodeMCU 0.9. My code:

```
 String message2 = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
      message2 += "<head>";
      message2 +=  "<title>Bootstrap Example</title>";
      message2 += " <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">";
      message2 += "<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">";
      message2 +=  "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>";
      message2 +=  "<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate alright, same author, same code

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered a similar question in a previous answer.

You use "before/after viewport in the fourth line, which should be prefixed with \ to make it an escape code to be treated like a " character instead of the start/end of a string.

Also afaik String is C++, as is the += operator, not C.

See [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/46508/nodemcu-and-expected-before-wrong)